# Power BI SSO using Spirng Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I want to implement SSO in the website using Spring Boot.

Can anyone tell me how can I implement SSO by login in website and allow users to show charts without login in Power BI?

I am using a free account of Power BI.

Comment: checkout here: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/11/20/add-sso-spring-boot-15-min

Comment: @OAH Thank you for the reference but I want it with Microsoft Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

On your Azure Portal, you will need to register an Enterprise Application and configure it for Single Sign on. You will also need to grant permissions to the PowerBI Service APIs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/register-app